# Automated testing UI Scalability for a web app

Tags: user-interface, automation, responsive-design, automated-tests

What automated tests would you consider to write when testing a web app's UI scalability? (a scalable UI - can dynamically scale up or down to fit bigger or smaller screens)

The only ideea that pops into my head is to test the css attributes of a particular element. eg: by changing the viewport of a website, the value for the width of a button will change from 100% to 80% size, you get that value and compare to the one you are expecting it to have.

Another thing that i was thinking about is that maybe the user won't be able to do a horizontal scroll, i know that this is possible to check via selenium/ cypress.

What other practical ideas pop to your mind?

Thanks!